# How to debug cro installation with zef

Tags: raku, cro, zef

I'd like to try some things with `raku` and `cro` but can't install it with:

```
zef install cro
```

I'm getting an error when it tries to install the module `YAMLish`. Running the installation with `--debug` gives:

```
[YAMLish] Extracting with plugin Zef::Service::Shell::tar aborted.
something went wrong extracting C:\Users\zb\AppData\Local\Temp/.zef/1698391208.16200\1698391222.16200.367.3485459071357\YAMLish%3Aver%3C0.0.6%3E%3Aauth%3Cgithub%3ALeont%3E.tar.gz
to C:\Users\zb\AppData\Local\Temp/.zef/1698391208.16200\YAMLish%3Aver%3C0.0.6%3E%3Aauth%3Cgithub%3ALeont%3E.tar.gz
with Zef::Service::Shell::git<3508240998224>,Zef::Service::FetchPath<3508225362272>,Zef::Service::Shell::tar<3508225362240>,Zef::Service::Shell::unzip<3508225361216>
```

The archive in question is present and was partly extracted to the target directory. If I were to guess, it seems to have choked on `yamlish-master/test-suite/meta` which contains a lot of [symbolic links](https://github.com/Leont/yamlish/tree/master/test-suite/meta) that point to non-existant files?

How can I resolve this or debug further? I'm running Rakudo v2023.10 on Windows 10.0.19045.3570.

Comment: Immediate workaround: `zef install YAMLish --force`, and then `zef install cro` again.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Running `zef install YAMLish --force` ends up with the same error, unfortunately...

Comment: Then I suggest making a zef issue: https://github.com/ugexe/zef as this appears to be an issue on Windows 10.  The YAMLish module installs fine on MacOS for me.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen [Issue opened](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/533)...

Comment: @zb226 I think it would be worth answering your own question now that you've figured out the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Update: The [issue was fixed](https://github.com/Leont/yamlish/issues/37#issuecomment-1783625641) a few hours later by YAMLish's maintainer*

---

With [help from ugexe](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/533) it became clear this is indeed caused by failure to create the symbolic links in question and that a workaround is to install directly from the [`YAMLish` github repo](https://github.com/Leont/yamlish):

```
zef install https://github.com/Leont/yamlish.git
```

Digging a bit deeper, I've found that creating symlinks in Windows (e.g. [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)) is only allowed

- with administrative privileges or
- in "Developer Mode" (added 2016 in [Windows 10 build 14972](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/))

Going either route allows installing the `YAMLish` module with just:

```
zef install YAMLish
```

Comment:   for writing the answer up. FWIW, having read the issue comments I presume similar sentiments apply to opening a YAMLish issue, suggesting not using symlinks, or at least mentioning the issue in its install messages or doc, and a Raku doc issue, mentioning that distributions should not contain symlinks if they are intended or expected to be platform agnostic. (I'll be happy to do one or both if you'd rather not.)

Comment: @raiph I've opened an [issue for YAMLish](https://github.com/Leont/yamlish/issues/37), can you do the one for the raku documentation?

Comment: Thanks. I've added a comment to an existing issue: https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/670#issuecomment-1783604966.